# C# Method Using Params Keyword

Tags: c#, parameters

An example of a method that uses the params keyword is `String.Format("", foo, bar, baz)`

But how would I make a method that accepts an array of enums like so:

```
class MyClass
{
    public enum Foo { Bar, Baz }

    public static void MyMethod(params enum[] Foo) {}

    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        MyMethod();
        MyMethod(Foo.Bar);
        MyMethod(Foo.Baz);
        MyMethod(Foo.Bar, Foo.Baz);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public static void MyMethod(params Foo[] values) { }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead

```
class MyClass
{
public enum Foo { Bar, Baz }

public static void MyMethod(params Foo[] foos) {}

public static void TestMethod()
{
    MyMethod();
    MyMethod(Foo.Bar);
    MyMethod(Foo.Baz);
    MyMethod(Foo.Bar, Foo.Baz);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Err..try:

```
public static void MyMethod(params Foo[] foo) { }
```

Comment: =p Thanks anyways. Do you know how I would merge the array of Foo enums with some defaults. for example I pass `MyMethod(Foo.Baz)` but I have `Foo.Bar` set as default so `foo` would equal `[Foo.Bar, Foo.Baz]`

Comment: No that wouldn't happen automatically for you. The closest to that would be either to drop `params` and use appropriate overloaded methods, where you can obviously specify the default yourself for the first arg, and pass the 2nd on to the method that takes two arguments. Alternatively, in C# 4.0, we will have optional and named method parameters.